# Force My Activity To Call The onSavedInstance State

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an android application in which I use two themes. On theme change I need to recreate all the activities and Fragments inside that to be recreated.

The same way our application get recreated using saved instnce state.

Is there any way I can force my Activity to call the saved instance state ? IF it is possible how I can do that ? If not why ? Is there any alternative to Achieve this ?

My current code looks like below.

```
public static final void restartActivity(final FragmentActivity activity){
    activity.finish();
    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
}
```

The issue with this is the fragment back stack is not getting recreated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: look at `onRestoreInstanceState()`

Comment: onSavedInstance state is not getting fired on close of the activity. So onRestoreInstanceState is not getting called and if fired also the saved instance state is null.

Comment: Not sure why you have a need to recreate an Activity, but you can just pass your data in Intent extras to new instance of activity and use it to "restore" state.

Answer (score 0):

Your state is not saved because you're creating a new instance of `Activity`. As a solution, you can pass your state to this new instance as `Intent` extras and restore state in `onCreate` from those extras.

Comment: It will really a tough task of recreating all the enclosing fragments inside the Activity my own by setting the arguments and I don think it could be a feasible solution. My question was is there any way to force my app to trigger the onSavedInstance state so that the state of the activity will be retained.